# Is it possible to customize main JFrame title rendering in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'd like to customize the title of my main JFrame on a Swing application.

There's two things I'd like to do, but can't find any way to achieve it :

- use an Image to put behind the title of the main JFrame. Something like this :
  http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=521357Untitled.png
- use a GradientPaint (or similar "tweak") to put a gradient color behind the title of the JFrame. Something like this : 
  http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=842390Untitled2.png

Is there any way to do that easily in Swing ?

Thanks,

Comment: The frame decorations are, for the most part, provided by the OS.  Some look and feels supply there own.  If you wanted to do this, you would need to supply your own look and feel from the classes you want to change.  Not a simple task

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll probably stick with the default decoration-style of Swing then ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify system native frames/dialogs decorations (including frame/dialog title).

Though there are two ways to modify the whole frame/dialog decoration:

1. You have to use some specific L&F in your application that has custom frame/dialog decorations and allows to change it - i don't really know if there is such. (you can find many L&Fs that have their own frame/dialog decorations, for example [this one](http://code.google.com/p/seaglass/))
2. You have to install your own RootPaneUI that will customize frame decoradion, but be aware that you will have to write all of the frame/dialog decoration features on your own (including window drag and resize, control buttons, title and others) - that requires a good knowledge of UIs, graphics and Swing.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Nimbus, and I'll take a look at what could be made with this LAF. Or I'll install seaglass as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another way (I used in Delphy some years ago...):

Don't display the default title bar, and put your own on one (made with all you want :p), and reimplement all the behaviaviour (drag n drop, maximize, minimize,...).

Comment: That is exactly what being done when RootPaneUI provides its own decoration. It simply undecorates the frame and adds its own decoration using swing components or graphics-based painting.